# Ecto "left IN right" query using a fragment

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I would like to query a jsonb field using postgres IN operator (with Ecto library)

This code work with a simple = operator:

```
from a in query, where: fragment("?->>'format' = ?", a.properties, "foo")
```

But I cannot make any of these attempts to work:

```
from a in query, where: fragment("?->>'format' IN ?", a.properties, ["foo", "bar"])
from a in query, where: fragment("?->>'format' IN (?)", a.properties, ["foo", "bar"])
from a in query, where: fragment("?->>'format' IN ?", a.properties, "('foo', 'bar')"])
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is the exact error/problem you're seeing?

Comment: One (ugly) thing that seems to work is to generate the list of terms beforehand, and then putting them in the query: `list = Enum.join(["foo", "bar"], ","); from a in query, where: fragment("?->>'format' IN (?)", a.properties, ^list])`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides Patrick's excellent response, keep in mind you can put only part of a query in a fragment too. For example, you can rewrite it to:

```
from a in query, where: fragment("?->>'format', a.properties) in ["foo", "bar"]
```

If you put the fragment in a macro, you can even get a readable syntax:

```
defmacro jsonb_get(left, right) do
  quote do
    fragment("?->>?", unquote(left), unquote(right))
  end
end
```

And now:

```
from a in query, where: jsonb_get(a.properties, "format") in ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: Oh, very nice! Gotta go refactor some queries ;-)

Comment: That's great, thanks! Ecto query is powerful but sometimes it seems a bit too magic for me :)

Comment: Very cool! Didn't realize you could embed fragments like that.

Answer (score 9):

This has nothing to do with JSONB in particular. Ecto will turn your list of types into a [Postgres `ARRAY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html), which does not work with the `IN` operator:

```
psql> SELECT 1 IN(ARRAY[1, 2, 3]);
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
```

However you can use [`= ANY()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20320) to check if the value is contained in an `ARRAY`:

```
psql> SELECT 1 = ANY(ARRAY[1, 2, 3]);
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

You should be able to use the following fragment to achieve the same with Ecto:

```
fragment("?->>'format' = ANY(?)", u.properties, ["foo", "bar"])
```

Comment: Indeed, I could see in log messages that my list was converted in a Postgres array, but I couldn't figure out what to do. Thanks!